# PHP: Locating oauth.php file in twitteroauth

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

I recently installed the contents of https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth and read somewhere that I'd only really need `oauth.php` and `twitteroauth.php` files for adding OAuth authentication in my Twitter app. I found the `twitteroauth.php` file in the `/twitteroauth-master/src` directory. However, I'm unable to locate the `oauth.php` file inside the `twitteroauth-master` directory.

Where exactly is the `oauth.php` located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation code of oauth that is listed in  [Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user) -

```
function getConnectionWithAccessToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken("abcdefg", "hijklmnop");
$content = $connection->

get("statuses/home_timeline");
```

But, the file itself can be found in the official repository - [Google Code OAuth.php](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php)

More details, Go to- https://code.google.com/p/oauth/ => php
You'll find it! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here the search results of "oauth.php" in this library:

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/find/master?q=oauth.php

There is no such file

Comment: I'm following two different tutorials now based on `twitteroauth` currently, and both make use of the `oauth.php` file. Does that mean that the current version of the `twitteroauth` library has removed that file?

Comment: It's possible... Try to seach it here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/twitter-app-oauth-php/ there is a download link, this may still have the oauth.php file

Comment: Also, I've found the download for the oauth.php file here: https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/downloads/list @ManasChaturvedi